# API: Contact get/getcount by primary address country stopped working on upgrade to 4.6.9

Tags: api, upgrade

I [spoke too soon](https://twitter.com/kragtbakker/status/652185995505475584), there was one hiccup on the recent upgrade.

I have a bit of custom code on one site that pulls contacts based on 'Primary Address country' as follows (example):

`$contactcount=civicrm_api("Contact","getcount", array ('version' =>'3', 'contact_type' =>'Organization', 'country' =>'United States');`

When I try this on the API Explorer on the demo site, I get this error:

`"error_message":"A fatal error was triggered: United States is not of the type Positive"`

[image: API Explorer]

It seems to have stopped working with an upgrade from 4.6.7 to 4.6.9. Did something change in the API call?

Update:

I was trying to rough in some temporary code to make this functional by using the Country ID instead of the Country Name, and there seems to be a problem there, too. The country ID field in the API seems to be essentially ignored.

`$contactcount=civicrm_api("Contact","getcount", array ('version' =>'3', 'contact_type' =>'Organization', 'country_id' => 1228);`

I verified this on the demo site, too. I have [opened a bug ticket for this](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17361).

Comment: A PR is submitted as a fix for the ticket mentioned - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6956

Comment: @JitendraPurohit If you add this as an answer I will select it.

Comment: will do that once the PR is merged, seems some optimisation & test fixes need to be done. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6985 where you can get the Contact using different address fields specifying the names (country, state_province, etc.)